# Rails: maintain session data in JS

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

How should I access Rails session data in JS? I need to access the "user_id" and whether the user is signed in for several js behaviors on my page.

**Store in JS is good:**

Doing an AJAX call every time I want to check seems unnecessary.

**Store in JS is bad:**

Storing the session data in JS means I need to keep it in sync with the server, which adds complexity.

**Options:**

1. Embed the "current_user" in a JS file on page load. Problem - This won't work since I use AJAX. The user may log and log-out via AJAX.
2. On page load, embed the @current_user in a JS file (or use Gon gem). Then use AJAX to change this JS object when needed. Problem - I can't embed Ruby in a "app/assets/js" file which would mean this could get messy and I'll be working with the object in 2 different places (unless you know a good approach)
   Other options?

Comment: Did you post the same question by accident, or are these two different? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20531328/rails-make-session-data-accessible-in-js

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy one is "how" and one is "should I"

Comment: Please delete one of your questions as they're both for the same solution.

Comment: Sorry guys didn't mean to post twice! meant to edit.

Comment: Deleted other question

Comment: Generally a js session is considered active until a 401 is received or the page is reloaded